# Run Pyomo model with externally assigned variables

Tags: pyomo, metaheuristics

I have several (large) Pyomo models with about 20 variables and parameters (as time series). Out of these variables and parameters I have 3 decision variables. Now my question is whether I can use this model to evaluate the solution when these 3 decision variables are externally assigned? The other variables are no decision variables. They can just be calculated once those 3 decision variables have a value (for every time slot as I use time series as variables).

The notion behind this approach is that I can for example use (or implement on my own) an evolutionary algorithm (or any other metaheuristic) for determining the values of the 3 decision variables and use the Pyomo model to evaluate the created solution (as it is necessary to calculate a fitness of a given solution when using evolutionary algorithms).

Of course I can also calculate a simulation for evaluating the solutions. But since I have more than 10 large models it would take quite a while to do so. This is why I would like to use my already existing Pyomo models.

Comment: Just fix these "decision variables" and solve.